# Creating sub-polygons based on underlying basemap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, digitizing, basemap

I'm looking at ranging patterns where animals go in and out of nature reserves into residential areas.  In addition to home range polygons, I've generated polygons made from applying 25m and 50m buffers to individual points and dissolving those points into a single polygon shapefile.

To my knowledge there aren't freely available quality maps of my areas of interest that specify broad landscape types categorically (suburban, urban, primary forest, reserve, secondary forest etc) so I've been working off of basemaps thus far.

I realize one option is to create these layers myself by digitizing over the basemap.  Alternately, I could create a feature class and freehand draw polygons over the reserve areas that overlap with the home range or buffered points.  One problem I'm encountering with this is that the freehand tool seems to automatically 'draw' where ever the cursor goes, rather than waiting for a definitive click - this is preventing me from zooming in and out and shifting window view as I would like to make an accurate rendering.

Are there any ways of drawing a polygon over an existing polygon without the cursor automatically 'drawing'?

I'm using ArcMap 10.2.2

I think my best bet would be to create the polygons islandwide so that I could just use the intersect tool going forward to determine the % of the range that falls into each category.

Comment: Why not use the Polygon construction tool instead of Freehand?  This will allow you to zoom in/out, pan, and click each vertex.